# How do I get dotless j (ȷ) from Helvetica in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, helvetica

I've the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\overrightarrow{\mathit{r}}=\mathit{r}\cos \mathit{\varphi}\widehat{\mathrm{\imath}}+\mathit{r}\sin \mathit{\varphi} \widehat{\mathrm{\jmath}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why did I get a black rectangle instead of a j unit vector?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you are fine with changing your font, you can use [Fira Math](https://github.com/firamath/firamath) which provides unicode-support. It contains dotless i and dotless j. That way, you can get greek letters which match sans-serif style as well. I don't know of any other sans-serif font with unicode-support.

Answer (score 8):

The `\imath` and `\jmath` symbols don’t come from your text font, which `helvet` sets to TeX Gyre Heros.  Unless you change it, they come from the 7-bit OML font.  In this case, you’re trying to do so with `mathastext`.

You probably want to explicitly load `tgheros`, [which does contain the ĵ and ȷ glyphs,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/qhv-info.pdf) rather than `helvet`.

Your options therefore include:

- Load `unicode-math` with a sans-serif math font.  As of 2020, that means Fira Math.
- Load a sans-serif math package, such as `sansmathfonts`, `arev` or `newtxsf`.
- Use the text-mode symbol in math mode. Define the symbol `\varj` as something like `\textnormal{\sffamily\itshape\selectfont \j}` and `\varjhat` as `\textnormal{\sffamily\itshape\selectfont ĵ}`.
- As above, but load `fontspec` and use *ĵ* from a Unicode font.

Answer (score 6):

helvet doesn't have the glyph and so you get the symbol for the `.notdef` glyph.

You could deactivate that mathastext tries to redefine it. And instead of writing \mathit everywhere, use the italic option of mathastext.

Be aware that helvet is not a math font. It misses chars and a number of math symbols, and imho the result looks rather bad. You can improve the greek e.g. with the option eulergreek (but then greek will be upright), but the arrows and accents still look too thin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unneeded in current tex systems
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[italic,defaultimath]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\overrightarrow{r}=r\cos \varphi\widehat{\mathrm{\inodot}}+r\sin \varphi \widehat{\jmath} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]